# How to set UILocalNotification for 30 consecutive days

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I want to schedule UILocalNotificaion for 30 consecutive days at 8:00 AM daily and i want to implement that functionality with one UILocationNotification instance only. Here is my code to schedule local notification.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [formatter dateFromString:@"08:00"];
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = date;
localNotification.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = @"You just received a local notification";
localNotification.alertAction = @"View Details";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[formatter release];
[date release];
```

It will fire daily notifications forever at 08:00AM, but i want to be notified for 30 consecutive days only. The easiest solution is to fire 30 UILocalNotifications but i want to do that with 1 UILocalNotification instance. How can i do that? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In UILocalNotification userInfo property save NSDate object when you create Notification.
When you open Notification,
check with the current date with date in userinfo . If there is difference is more than 30 days you can cancel your local notification.

Comment: Your solution will work if user checks or receives a notification. But what if user does not receive or check any notification?

Comment: @ShahidIqbal have found an answer to this specific question?

Comment: @llario I think i have to go with Kareem's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

// now a NSDate object for now + 30 days
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:30];
NSDate *endDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:now options:0];
```

After that check:

```
if([currentDate isEarlierDate:endDate]){
//Fire the notification
}
```